# DotNet HighChart not working in Update Panel (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, highcharts

I have asp.net web application i have added multiple dot net highchart in the same page.(Like Dashboard) those charts wrapped in the Update panel. i have tried all the google links as possible to find ways to update each chart interdependently.

i am using timer to refresh them. also update panels are set to `Conditional` update. 
that dose not work at all.

What can i do?

```
<div style="" id="asdFlick" class="leftSideBoxChart"  >
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Literal ID="ltrWeekToatalLineChart" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="70000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
    </div>
```

Comment: let us see your code,so we can help you.

Comment: what did you do? I'm facing the same problem... when you refresh the whole page every thing is fine, but as soon as you decide to do it with an UpdatePanel the chart won't display. I think we should do something in client side...